# Why don't I get a closing XML node for each pass through this loop?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am pulling some records from a MySQL database. No problem there, I have 48,000 records to work with. I am getting all of the data.  I have looked at this 'til my eyes are swimming.  When I try to convert the rows to XML the structured should be:

```
<listings>
    <listing (some attributes)></listing>
    <listing (some attributes)></listing>
    <listing (some attributes)></listing>
</listings>
```

Instead the XML is structured like this:

```
<listings>
    <listing (some attributes> 
        <listing (some attributes> 
           <listing (some attributes>
           </listing>
        </listing>
     </listing>
</listings>
```

Here is the declaration and the loop that creates the xml:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$node = $dom->createElement("listings");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      // Add to XML document node
      $node = $dom->createElement("listing");
      $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
      $newnode->setAttribute("id",$row['id']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("title",$row['title']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("latitude",$row['latitude']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("longitude",$row['longitude']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append that node after you are done building it:

```
<?php

$arr = [
  [
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'title 1',
    'latitude' => '1.1',
    'longitude' => '2.1'
  ],
  [
    'id' => 2,
    'title' => 'title 2',
    'latitude' => '1.2',
    'longitude' => '2.2'
  ],
];

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$parnode = $dom->createElement("listings");
while ($row = array_shift($arr)){
      // Add to XML document node
      $newnode = $dom->createElement("listing");
      $newnode->setAttribute("id",$row['id']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("title",$row['title']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("latitude",$row['latitude']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("longitude",$row['longitude']);
      $parnode->appendChild($newnode);
}
$dom->appendChild($parnode);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<listings>
    <listing id="1" title="title 1" latitude="1.1" longitude="2.1"></listing> 
    <listing id="2" title="title 2" latitude="1.2" longitude="2.2"></listing> 
</listings>
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LUjHg)

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Also, don't use the error suppression operator (`@`) as it hides error messages that may be helpful in debugging your code. You should also always write your code so it does not generate any PHP errors including notices.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  With respect to the older code, I have taken on a project where the site had been neglected for a few years.  There is a third party security product called ionCube that encrypts certain files and the site requires PHP 5.3 in order run.  We had to drop the test box back to PHP 5.3!  Hopefully at some point we'll have budget to address that problem.  Again, thanks so very much.  It's been several years since I've had to write any code. Have used prepared SQL statements with Java MVC but again, it's been a while.  Developing on a shoe string.budget.